# Is it possible to create a list of form fields from an array in Android?

Tags: java, android

For example, given:

```
String[] formFields = {"name","description","notes"};
```

Can I create a list of EditText fields in Android using that array instead of hard coding the EditText fields?

Comment: Yes that is possible, any other questions?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a Java and Android beginner and just trying to learn how to do so. I googled for the last hour trying to find an example on how to do so but couldn't find any examples.

Comment: I will write a proper answer shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
String[] array = new String[] { "A", "B", "C" };

int previousId = 0;

// Loop through all the Strings in the array
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

    // Get the text from the array
    String text = array[i];

    // Create a new EditText
    EditText editText = new EditText(context);

    // To add the Rules for the position of the views later on we need to define an id.
    // In this case I assign the index in the array as Id, but in your app you should define
    // ids in values/ids.xml like this: <item name="firstEditText" type="id" /> and use these
    editText.setId(i + 1);

    // Set the text for the new EditText
    editText.setText(text);

    // Create the LayoutParams
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    // Add the rules where to place the view.
    if(i == 0) {

        // The first EditText will be placed at the top of the parent.
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);

    } else {

        // All EditTexts after the first one are placed below the previous one.
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, previousId);

    }

    // We save the id of this EditText so we can position the next EditText below it.
    previousId = editText.getId();    

    // Add the view to your layout - in this case a RelativeLayout - with the LayoutParams we defined above
    relativeLayout.addView(editText, params);
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that you just upvoted alot of my answers? While I appreciate that it won't do much good. This practice which is called serial upvoting falls under voting fraud and is frowned upon. It will automatically be reversed within the next 24 hours. There is no punishment for doing this but if you continue to engage in such behaviour you might be banned or face other kinds of restrictions. [Here you can find more information about serial upvoting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126857). There are other options to reward an answerer beyond upvoting and accepting like the bounty system.

Comment: Being a beginner, I was actually reading through your other Android answers while waiting for your response. Should I remove those votes?

Comment: I think by now those votes are locked in and you cannot remove them anymore. You can try if you want to, but one incident of serial upvoting will have no negative effect on you. The system just detects cases were one person upvoted alot of answers of another person and if found reserves them. Such upvoting is not considered normal behaviour. But since there are cases were this might not have been a case of voting fraud there is no automatic punishment in place. If you want more information you can visit the link in my previous comment. But I appreciate that you think my answers are helpful!

Comment: As I said to reward an answerer beyond upvoting and accepting you can use the [bounty system](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067).

Comment: Oh okay. Thank you so much for the information :) I upvoted each of the answers I read after I got your answer for this one. I'll be sure to upvote one after I read them instead of upvoting a bunch at the same time next time. I appreciate your help on this. You've been extremely helpful. Thank you so much again Xaver!

Comment: Sorry to bother you again Xaver. How would I place line breaks between the fields? Right now the fields are in a single line, but I'd like to have the each form field on top of each other. I tried "editText.setLines(2)" and "editText.setSingleLine(false);" and many others for the last hour but can't seem to do it.

Comment: You mean the position of the `EditTexts` is not correct? In what kind of layout are you placing the `EditTexts`?

Comment: Right now, from your code above, the fields are placed horizontally (side by side). I'd like to place the fields vertically (one on top of each other). Is that possible?

Comment: Yeah I understand that, but to what kind of layout are you adding the `EditTexts`?

Comment: I'm using the RelativeLayout. Is that what you mean? :)

Comment: Yes that is what I mean, in that case you need to add rules to the `LayoutParams` that define where the `Views` should be placed. I will edit my answer, but I don't have a solid internet connection right now, so it might take a while for me to submit the edits to my answer.

Comment: Awesome. I will test out the LayoutParams and see if I can get it in the meantime. Big thanks again for the help Xaver!

Comment: I have edited my answer, unfortunately I couldn't test my code right now but I am confident that it should work. If there are any errors I apologise in advance.

Comment: Thanks Xaver. I tried it but the fields are actually all on one line and stacked/overlapped at the top-left hand corner. No worries though because I know you can't test it right now :)

Comment: Hi Xaver. The "A" and "B" fields are still stacked in one position in the top left. The "C" however is on a new line below.

Comment: I have edited my answer, I forgot that ids with a value of 0 are not allowed, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you Xaver :) No convenience whatsoever. I apologize for taking so much of your time. Thank you thank you. You're the best Xaver. Thank you so much!!